# Handwritten digit recognition with neural network - using RBM

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

assume there are many training samples of 20x20 pixel'd handwritten digits. I trained them with multi-layered Restriected Boltzmann Machine neural network. The top layer consists of 10-neuron that each means number 0~9.

The problem is, RBM's not classifying those 0~9. It actually classfies digits into 10-kinds, but that 10 kinds does not match digits 0~9:

```
0th neuron matches '4'
1st neuron matches differently shaped '4'
2nd neuron matches '3'....
```

It seems the top layer needs supervised learning but I have only Contrastive-Divergence learning which is the most common training method of RBMs. Any tips?

Comment: When you're training keep track of your label and try to print the exact exception at the place of the output. Instead of training your data with RBM you should try with kernel svm. I think at the time of classification of your data, your classification becomes noisy so I would suggest you should try training your data with svm or RandomForest. If you'll get the output with these models(hopefully not), you'll be able to understand your errors.